How do I return a pointer from a function that returns a template abstract class?
I have 2 classes, BaseArrayList which is an abstract template class, and ArrayList which is derived from BaseArrayList.
I have the user enter the type of the list they want, and I need to create a BaseArrayList pointer to point to the list, but the problem is if I use if/switch statements then they are not declared outside the scope.
template <typename T>
class BaseArrayList{
public:
    virtual ~BaseArrayList(){};
    virtual void add(const T element) = 0;
    virtual void remove(const int index) = 0;
    virtual void get(const int index) const = 0;
    virtual void print() const = 0;
    virtual void fullPrint() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class ArrayList : public BaseArrayList<T>{
private:
    T *arr;
    int size;
    int capacity;
public:
    ArrayList(const unsigned int capacity){
        // constructor
    }
    ~ArrayList(){
        // desctructor
    }
    void add(const T element) override{
        // some code
    }
    void remove(const int index) override{
        // some code
    }
    void get(const int index) const override{
        // some code
    }
    void print() const override{
        // some code
    }
    void fullPrint() const override{
        // some code
    }
};

template <typename T>
BaseArrayList<T>* createArrayType(const unsigned int type){
    unsigned int capacity = inputCapacity();

    switch (type){
        case 1: return new ArrayList<int>(capacity); break;
        case 2: return new ArrayList<double>(capacity); break;
        case 3: return new ArrayList<char>(capacity); break;
        case 4: return new ArrayList<string>(capacity); break;
        default: return nullptr;
    }
}

int main(){
     unsigned int type = arrayType();

     BaseArrayList* list = createArrayType(type);
}

The compiler shows 2 errors:

cannot deduce class template arguments


no instance of function template "createArrayType" matches the argument list

I could just make 4 different pointers for all each type, or use an if/switch to create a pointer based on the user input, but then the scope of the pointers is only inside the if which is a major problem.
I tried to make the createArrayType function a template, but then the compiler throws an error saying it doesn't know what type of pointer to return.

createArrayType is a template function. You need to specify template arguments in its call.

Also BaseArrayList* can't be done. BaseArrayList is a template, not a type. You need a common base for your polymorphism to work. You could move add to the implementation and then make the base class template into a proper class: example

you didn't specify any memory to your T *arr!.

get() returns void, but from the name, I'd expect it to return an array element.  And if it did this, it would need to move to the implementation too, since the return type would be based on the class template parameter.

Generally a runtime value cannot change a compile time type of a variable.
A std::variant however lets you store multiple possible runtime types in one compile time type.
CreateArrayType can return a std::variant<BadeArrayType<int>*, BaseArrayType<double>*, BaseArrayType<char>*, BaseArrayType<std::string>*>.
You now have to learn how to work with std variants.
std::visit([&](auto* parray){
  /* code */
}, variantOfArrays);

is one way to work with them.
The general plan you have, however, is not compatible with C++'s compile time type system.  So you will have to do additional work.

You could try to use std::any for type erasure of your base class, and then have a templated derived class that will std::any_cast the values and store them in a classic container.
Simplified example:
class BaseArrayList{
public:
    virtual ~BaseArrayList(){};
    virtual void add(const std::any& elem) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class ArrayList : public BaseArrayList {
private:
    std::vector<T> arr;
public:
    void add(const std::any& elem) override {
        // can throw std::bad_any_cast
        arr.push_back(std::any_cast<T>(elem));
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<BaseArrayList> createArrayType(const unsigned int type) {
    switch (type){
        case 1: return std::make_unique<ArrayList<int> >(); break;
        case 2: return std::make_unique<ArrayList<double> >(); break;
        case 3: return std::make_unique<ArrayList<char> >(); break;
        case 4: return std::make_unique<ArrayList<std::string> >(); break;
        default: return nullptr;
    }
}

Note however, that you need to pay attention to use exactly the correct types, e.g. this
auto arr = createArrayType(4);
arr->add("abc");

will throw std::bad_any_cast, because "abc" is const char*, not std::string. So you need to arr->add(std::string{"abc"}); instead.
